# How is initializing an array different from mallocing memory?

Tags: arrays, memory-management, c++

I am new to C++. I am having trouble differentiating between initializing an array and mallocing memory. To me, they seem to accomplish the same purpose.

Specifically, I can initialize an array via `int myArray[] = {1, 2, 3};`. I can also use `malloc` to obtain memory and assign it to a void pointer. Later, I free this memory.

What is the difference between these two methods? Does a computer store the data in the same places and in the same ways?

Answer (score 2):

In C++ there are two different ways you can allocate memory. The first way allocates memory on the stack.

```
int arr[] = {1,2,3};
int arr[3];
```

Both of these lines of code create an array of size 3 on the stack. The only difference is the first line also initializes the values in the array.

The second way you can allocate memory is on the heap. The amount of memory available on the heap is usually much larger than is available on the stack. The `new` and `malloc` operations allocate memory on the heap.

```
int* arr = (int*) malloc(100*sizeof(int));
int* arr = new int[100];
```

Both of these lines of code create an array of size 100 on the heap. Now here's the difference between the two. In C++ you should always use `new` because it ensures that the constructors for each element in your array are called. It is also much more type safe, unlike `malloc` which isn't type safe at all since it just returns a `void*` to a chunk of bytes that can be interpreted anyway you'd please.

Now if you're dynamically allocating memory, meaning you don't know the size of the array until runtime, you should always allocate it on the heap using `new`/`malloc`.

Last thing to note is how you free your memory, using `delete`/`free`.

```
free(arr); //arr was allocated with malloc
delete[] arr; //arr was allocated with new
```

If you allocated memory with `new` it must be freed with `delete`. You can't mix and match `new`/`malloc` with `delete`/`free`. Lastly `delete[]` frees an array of objects. If you only allocated a single object then you just use `delete`.

```
Object* myobj = new Object;
delete myobj;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, this question does not belong to here. But I will answer it. You can do that with:

```
 int* myArray = (int *) malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
```

This means that you are creating memory location with memory size 3 * sizeof(int) [i.e. the size of the integer data type in C], and you re returning an int pointer to this memory location. [i.e. a pointer that points to the beginning of it, and deal with it as it if contains integers]. These memory slots are converted to int * (using (int *)), and called myArray. myArray is an int array (and an int pointer). Because arrays are actually pointers in C. Then you do:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) 
     myArray[i] = i + 1;
```

There could be some issues in malloc. Therefore, after the initialization always check if myArray == NULL. If this is case, fix the error, and dont initialize the array with $\{1,2,3\}$. Otherwise, you will get a segmentation fault.

I wish I am not vague to you. But since you are using C++, I would suggest you use the new operator instead. you would do:

```
 int myArray[] = new int[3];
```